# Java(Ant) application connected to MySql database table but not reading values

Tags: java, mysql

Attached is the button with the code for the connection inside it(For privacy reasons I'm removing the password from the code.). I know(through trial and error) that the button works with no issues, the application is successfully connected to the database table and that that everything that's supposed to be case sensitive is typed correctly. I also tried a different MySql connector(java.8.0.30.jar). I will attach a snip of the [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhDjq.png) . Both username and password are type varchar if that makes a difference(I've tried changing them to type text). Both values are "Dox" on the database. The only logical reason I can think of is that there's something wrong with the query I'm using but I've tried many different ones and non work. The output is the else statement . There are no error messages in the compiler. I'm using MySql as my database and NetBeans 15 as my IDE. Sorry if this is too much information...still relatively new here

```
loginButtonF.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rgi_student", "root", "");
            PreparedStatement pst = null;

            ResultSet rs = null;

            String sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM richfield.members Where username = ? AND password = ?";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sqlquery);
            pst.setString(1, user);
            pst.setString(2, pass);
            rs = pst.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome" + " " + user);
            }

            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Password or Username");
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
});
```

Declaration of user and pass

```
String user = userTxtF.getText(); 
String pass = passwordTxtF.getText();
```

Comment: Saving passwords in clear text is very dangerous as Nd muß b es avoided

Comment: *String user = userTxtF.getText(); String pass = passwordTxtF.getText();* Those local variables are not present in the method bodies you have posted. IOW that can't be the real code

Comment: Have you tried the query in some MySQL client? What's the result?

Comment: Do you have instance variables named 'user' and 'pass' as well as those local ones? If so, those local variables I referred to earlier will prevent them being assigned to, with the result that they might well be empty when you try to use them in that query

Comment: @g00se you're right it wasn't in the main method in the application as well. I didn't know it would matter since there was no error message. I learnt something new. Once I moved it into the method it worked perfectly.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the declaration of user and pass were outside of the method/code for the button. I would never have thought that the solution to this would be so simple. Thanks to [g00se](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16376827/g00se) for pointing that out in the comments:

> *String user = userTxtF.getText(); String pass = passwordTxtF.getText();* Those local variables are not present in the method bodies you have posted. IOW that can't be the real code – [g00se](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16376827/g00se) [Oct 24 at 23:05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74187538/javaant-application-connected-to-mysql-database-table-but-not-reading-values/74188235#comment130983932_74187538)

> Do you have instance variables named 'user' and 'pass' as well as those local ones? If so, those local variables I referred to earlier will prevent them being assigned to, with the result that they might well be empty when you try to use them in that query – [g00se](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16376827/g00se) [Oct 24 at 23:28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74187538/javaant-application-connected-to-mysql-database-table-but-not-reading-values/74188235#comment130984186_74187538)

> @g00se you're right it wasn't in the main method in the application as well. I didn't know it would matter since there was no error message. I learnt something new. Once I moved it into the method it worked perfectly.Thank you! – [Dox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20325375/dox) [Oct 25 at 1:09](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74187538/javaant-application-connected-to-mysql-database-table-but-not-reading-values/74188235#comment130985063_74187538)

Comment: As late a call as possible to the components holding the user data is what you want, so call those methods in the```ps.setString``` calls